# Firebase / Recaptcha / Ionic / Angular - Cannot assign to read only property 'taskData' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, recaptcha, angularfire2

I have an Ionic app (`@ionic/angular: 4.0.0-beta.17`) and I'm using Firebase as my Authenticator (via @angular/fire).

Whenever I try to sign in with a phone number, I pass the number (as E.164) and the `appVerifier`, and I made an invisible recaptcha. I can assure you that these values are valid.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
```

Unexpectedly, I get a TypeError from Recaptcha:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'taskData' of object '[object Object]'
>
> ```
> at HTMLDivElement.addEventListener (zone.js:1829)
> at gg (recaptcha__iw.js:91)
> at Vp (recaptcha__iw.js:89)
> at He.Ot.A (recaptcha__iw.js:163)
> at am (recaptcha__iw.js:566)
> at He.am.render (recaptcha__iw.js:565)
> at iW (recaptcha__iw.js:569)
> at Oi (recaptcha__iw.js:578)
> at jJ.w.CQ.jJ.a0.jJ.Eu (recaptcha__iw.js:573)
> at Object.Ei [as reset] (recaptcha__iw.js:574)
> ```

This is the whole process of authentication:

```
return firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
  .then(result => (windowRef as any).confirmationResult = result)
  .catch(err => { // <-- returns error
    appVerifier.render().then(widgetId => grecaptcha.reset(widgetId));
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
```

After that error occurs, I get another error regarding this line:

```
appVerifier.render().then(widgetId => grecaptcha.reset(widgetId));
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null
>
> ```
> at jJ.w.CQ.jJ.a0.jJ.Eu (recaptcha__iw.js:573)
> at Object.Ei [as reset] (recaptcha__iw.js:574)
> at auth.state.ts:107 <----- (the line I mentioned above)
> at e.g (auth.esm.js:17)
> at Fb (auth.esm.js:20)
> at Bb (auth.esm.js:20)
> at A.push../node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js.g.Xb (auth.esm.js:19)
> at kb (auth.esm.js:13)
> at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
> at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
> ```

For some reason, when I downgrade the package `@ionic/angular` back to version `4.0.0-beta.15`, it seems to work. I have no idea what's happening behind the scene.

I'm not sure if this bug is related to Ionic or Recaptcha or Firebase.

#### package.json (deps only)

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/fire": "~5.1.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
  "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.8",
  "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
  "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
  "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
  "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
  "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.0.0-beta.25",
  "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.21",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.21",
  "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.17",
  "@ionic/pro": "^2.0.3",
  "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.0",
  "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
  "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "@ngxs/form-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "@ngxs/router-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "@ngxs/store": "^3.2.0",
  "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
  "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
  "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "2.4.6",
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.1",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
  "core-js": "^2.5.3",
  "firebase": "^5.5.8",
  "libphonenumber-js": "^1.6.5",
  "lodash": "^4.17.11",
  "rxjs": "6.2.2",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.8.5",
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.5",
  "@angular-devkit/core": "~0.8.5",
  "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~0.8.5",
  "@angular/cli": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
  "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^1.0.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/lodash": "^4.14.119",
  "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
  "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~3.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.4.0",
  "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
  "tslint": "~5.11.0",
  "typescript": "~3.1.6"
},
```

#### $ ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.5.0 (C:\Users\Eliya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.17
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.8.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.8
   @angular/cli                  : 7.0.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.1, (and 5 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (E:\android-sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.11.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```